# Menu in system status bar is disabled

Tags: swift, appkit

```
 func createStatusItem() -> NSStatusItem {
        let item = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        item.button?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "archivebox.fill", accessibilityDescription: "")
        item.menu = createMenu()
        return item;
    }

    func createMenu() -> NSMenu {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "Cap Status Bar Menu")

        menu.addItem(
                withTitle: "Order a burrito",
                action: #selector(StatusBarFactory.x(_:)),
                keyEquivalent: "A")

        menu.addItem(
                withTitle: "Cancel burrito order",
                action: #selector(StatusBarFactory.x(_:)),
                keyEquivalent: "B")

        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())

        let i = NSMenuItem(title: "test", action: #selector(StatusBarFactory.x(_:)), keyEquivalent: "T");
        menu.addItem(i)
        return menu
    }
```

This creates menu in system status bar but all items are DISABLED!

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [menu items disabled in macOS menubar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408379/menu-items-disabled-in-macos-menubar-app)

Comment: Knowing the answer, I can see it in the mentioned post. Without it, it is hard to find it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu validation does not find any implementor of specified action in responder chain so disable it. You have to specify target for each menu item:

```
    let item = menu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order a burrito",
            action: #selector(StatusBarFactory.x(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: "A")
    item.target = _instance_of_StatusBarFactory_here // like StatusBarFactory.shared
```